# Is it haram to build a system which will be used at the end for haram purposes?

Tags: halal-haram

I am a [programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2742371/houssni) and I have been thinking about something for a **very** long time.

At the moment I am working for a company who has a beer website. I, the developer, have built the entire system of this alcoholic website but I am really afraid the money I earned with it is haram-money and that it was a sin to build a system for this website.

Is it haram to build a system which will be used at the end for haram purposes?

<sub>By the way, I had nothing to do with the content (pictures, texts etc..) and the site is *not* selling it</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> God’s curse falls on ten groups of people who deal with alcohol. The one who distills it, the one for whom it has been distilled, the one who drinks it, the one who transports it, the one to who it has been brought, the one whom serves it, the one who sells it, **the one who utilizes money from it**, the one who buys it and the one who buys it for someone else." - Sunan Ibn-I-Majah Volume 3, Book of Intoxicants, Chapter 30 Hadith No. 3380.

It would seem that the answer depends on whether you profit from the sale of alcohol.

Comment: The website only provides information about alcohol and where to buy, the company itself does not sell alcohol. What would be the case?

Comment: In a way it is wrong cause they(people who are making the site) are helping them to sell alcohol if you are a employee then it not your fault but if you can reject the project it would be better but In the end Allah know all. and may Allah guide you.

Comment: @Hamza I really appreciate your answer and help, jazak Allah, you definitely helped me a lot here.